# I get an std::bad_variant_access exception when I try to access the structure type

Tags: c++, c++17, std

The structures that I use

```
#pragma pack(push, 1)
struct shortCommand
{
    shortCommand() { cop = r1 = r2 = 0; }
    uint8_t cop;
    uint8_t r1 : 4;
    uint8_t r2 : 4;
};
#pragma pack(pop)

struct longCommand
{
    shortCommand sCmd;
    uint16_t addres;
    longCommand() { addres = 0; }
};

union WORD
{
    std::variant<int, unsigned int, float> data;
    std::variant<shortCommand, doubleShortCmd, longCommand> commands;
    WORD() { data = 0; }
};
```

The problematic function

```
void loadLong(istringstream & stream, CPU & cpu)
{
    WORD word; string temp;
    word.data = 0;
    uint16_t addr = 0;
    auto f = [&](istringstream &stream, auto &val)
    {
        stream >> temp;
        val = stoi(temp);
        temp.clear();
    };

    uint8_t r1 = 0, r2 = 0;
    uint16_t opcode, addres;
    f(stream, addr);
    f(stream, std::get<2>(word.commands).sCmd.cop); // At this point, I catch an unhandled exception std:: bad_variant_access
    f(stream, r1);
    f(stream, r2);
    f(stream, std::get<2>(word.commands).addres);  //Here too

    optype op;
    op.l = true;
    cpu.operator_type.insert({ addr, op });
    cpu._mem.pushWord(word, addr);
}
```

Cppreference writes that such an exception can be caught if we try to get a type that is not in the list of alternative types.
I started using `std::variant` only recently, and I want to find out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: [`std::get`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/get) will throw that exception if you try to get something in the variant that is not the current alternative.  I think you want to create a temporary `longCommand`, read into that with `f`, and then assign it to `word.commands`.

Comment: There's **a lot** of things wrong with your code I don't know where to begin (e.g. why is `string temp` not local to `f`? Why is `WORD` capitalized when it isn't a macro? Why are you mixing `union` with `variant`? Why is `shortCommand` using so many packing features seemingly unnecessarily for this application? (Because a `variant` still uses the same memory as its largest member)

Comment: You have to assign it directly, then you can read it.

read up on std::variant<Tys...>::operator=

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the error because nowhere in `loadLong` do you initialize `WORD word`'s `.commands` field. You should be getting compiler warnings about this (are you compiling with `-Wall`?)

Also, using an outer C-style `union` is unneeded because `std::variant` is a type-safe representation of a [discriminated union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union).

Answer (score 0):

I created a temporary longcommand object, initialized the fields, and assigned commands via word :)

```
WORD word;
    uint8_t r1 = 0, r2 = 0;
    longCommand lCmd;
    f(stream, addr);
    f(stream, lCmd.sCmd.cop);
    f(stream, r1); lCmd.sCmd.r1 = r1;
    f(stream, r2); lCmd.sCmd.r2 = r2;
    f(stream, lCmd.addres);
    word.commands = lCmd;
```

P.S Sorry for the code you see now, I'm a very bad programmer.